# DataGridView display turns into a mess when scrolling

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a windows form with a DataGridView with multiple data binding sources.  The form loads correctly with the appropriate data,

[image: Original DGV]

but when i scroll (either scrollbar or mouse wheel), it turns into this:
[image: scroll DGV]

If i refresh the form on new line selection, it goes back to the top of the form. I see that there is a DataGridView.Scroll event. What do i need to do with it? Is there something else that i need to change to make my form look pretty again?

thx!

**EDIT**

Below is the code that is run to the point.  There is nothing additional that handles the way the form is drawn/redrawn, and there is no event handling on DataGridView1.scroll

```
Imports datagridviewautofilter
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class AssignShipDateForm


'sql datastream connection variables
Dim Conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection         'sql server datastream connection
Dim Cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand             'sql command vars
Dim SqlQuery As String                                      'string var used to hold various SQL queries
Dim SqlInsertQuery As String                                'sql insert query for data adapter
Dim SqlUpdateQuery As String                                'sql update query for data adapter
Dim SqlDeleteQuery As String                                'sql delete query for data adapter
Dim data As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader             'datareader object variable
Dim ConnString As String
Dim da As SqlDataAdapter

'MasterVars table variables
Public Vers As String = Nothing                             'tally sheet version
Public Testing As Boolean = False                           'tf testing
Public SendMailAcct As String = Nothing                     'send email account for automated emails
Public SendMailPW As String = Nothing                       'password for email account
Public SMTPUseSSL As Boolean = True                         ' SMTP SSL
Public SMTPAuthenticate As Integer = 0                      'Authenticate SMTP
Public SMTPServer As String = Nothing                       'Email Server
Public SendUsing As Integer = 0                             'Send Using
Public SMTPServerPort As Integer = 0                        'SMTP Email Server Port
Public TestingEmail As String = Nothing                     'email account that all emails should be directed to when version is testing
Public PrePricingEmail As String = Nothing                  'email account that all prod prepricing emails should be directed to
Public ImperataEmail As String = Nothing                    'email account that all prod Imperata emails should be directed to (for permits etc)
Public DirectShipEmail1 As String = Nothing                 'email account that all prod direct ship orders should be directed to
Public DirectShipEmail2 As String = Nothing                 'email account that all prod direct ship orders should be directed to
Public DirectShipEmail3 As String = Nothing                 'email account that all prod direct ship orders should be directed to
Public DirectShipEmail4 As String = Nothing                 'email account that all prod direct ship orders should be directed to

'user security variables
Public EMailAddress As String = Nothing                     'User's email address
Public ThePersonsName As String = Nothing                   'User's name
Public Logistics As String = Nothing                        'logistics module access level

'close form with changes pending variables
Dim CloseForm As New Shared_Code.SharedCode
Dim ShouldICloseForm As String = Nothing                    'determiniation if the form should be closed or not

'error reporting variables
Dim ErrorReporting As New ErrorReporting.ErrorReporting
Public Shared ErrCode As String = Nothing                   'error code
Public Shared ErrVar As String = Nothing                    'variable that caused error
Public Shared ErrorCounter As Integer = 0                   'error Counter
Public Shared ErrAct As Boolean = False                     't/f fatal error

'INITIALIZE FORM
Dim FirstPass As Boolean = True                             't/f switch to determine if form initialize is on a first pass or subsequent pass

'CELL VALUE CHANGED
Dim RowUpdated As Boolean = False                           't/f flag to set if the row has been updated
Dim SelectedShipDate As String = Nothing                    'selected ship date 
Dim SelectedShipDateCounter As Integer = 0                  'selected ship date PKEY for TempTable
Dim NumberOfTrucksAvailable As Integer = 0                  'number of trucks available for selected Ship Date
Dim DefaultPickDateCounter As Integer = 0                   'counter (PKEY) for default pick date
Dim DefaultPickDate As String = Nothing                     'default pick date derived from PKEY
Dim i As Integer = 0                                        'counter variable for adding number of trucks available from MasterBusinessDatesTable

'SAVE BUTTON
Dim vbYN As String = Nothing                                'vbyn for msgbox
Dim PickID As String = Nothing                              'Pkey for logistics records
Dim DTS As DateTime = Nothing                               'DTS for updates

'********************************************************************************
'*                                                                              *
'*CBB00: FORM LOAD                                                              *
'*                                                                              *
'********************************************************************************
Public Sub New(ByRef vers As String, ByRef testing As Boolean, ByRef SendMailAcct As String, ByRef SendMailPW As String, ByVal SMTPUseSSL As Boolean, ByVal SMTPAuthenticate As Integer, ByVal SMTPServer As String, ByVal SendUsing As Integer, ByVal SMTPServerPort As Integer, ByRef TestingEmail As String, ByRef PrePricingEmail As String, ByRef ImperataEmail As String, ByRef DirectShipEmail1 As String, ByRef DirectShipEmail2 As String, ByRef DirectShipEmail3 As String, ByRef DirectShipEmail4 As String, ByRef EMailAddress As String, ByRef ThePersonsName As String, ByRef Logistics As String)

    InitializeComponent()

    Me.Vers = vers
    Me.Testing = testing
    Me.SendMailAcct = SendMailAcct
    Me.SendMailPW = SendMailPW
    Me.SMTPUseSSL = SMTPUseSSL
    Me.SMTPAuthenticate = SMTPAuthenticate
    Me.SMTPServer = SMTPServer
    Me.SendUsing = SendUsing
    Me.SMTPServerPort = SMTPServerPort
    Me.TestingEmail = TestingEmail
    Me.PrePricingEmail = PrePricingEmail
    Me.ImperataEmail = ImperataEmail
    Me.DirectShipEmail1 = DirectShipEmail1
    Me.DirectShipEmail2 = DirectShipEmail2
    Me.DirectShipEmail3 = DirectShipEmail3
    Me.DirectShipEmail4 = DirectShipEmail4
    Me.EMailAddress = EMailAddress
    Me.ThePersonsName = ThePersonsName
    Me.Logistics = Logistics

    'set connection string and form for prod vs. test
    If testing = True Then
        ConnString = "data Source=SQL01;Initial Catalog=TallySheetTest;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
        Me.Text = "Assign Ship Dates " & vers & " TESTING"
    Else
        ConnString = "data Source=SQL01;Initial Catalog=TallySheet;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
        Me.Text = "Assign Ship Dates " & vers
    End If

    For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
        col.HeaderCell = New DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell(col.HeaderCell)
    Next

    DataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
    DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True

    Call FormInitialize()

End Sub

'********************************************************************************
'*                                                                              *
'*CBC00: FORM INITIALIZE                                                        *
'*                                                                              *
'********************************************************************************
Public Sub FormInitialize()

    'clear Dataset
    Me.TallySheetDataSet.Clear()

    If FirstPass = True Then
        'Do nothing
    Else
        '????????
    End If

    FirstPass = False

    'Set buttons
    Select Case Logistics
        Case "I"
            Button1.Enabled = False
            Button2.Enabled = False
        Case Else
            Button1.Enabled = True
            Button2.Enabled = False
    End Select

    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'TallySheetDataSet.TruckTypeTable' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.TruckTypeTableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TallySheetDataSet.TruckTypeTable)

    'SPCBC0001 Check if TempTable1 is empty
    Try
        Using Conn = New SqlConnection(ConnString)
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
            cmd.Connection = Conn
            cmd.CommandText = "SPCBC0001"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Conn.Open()
            data = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            data.Read()
            If data.HasRows = True Then
                ErrCode = "CBC00-03"
                ErrVar = "TempTable1"
                ErrorCounter = ErrorCounter + 1
                ErrAct = ErrorReporting.YouBrokeMyProgram("", ErrCode, ErrVar, ErrorCounter, Testing, Vers, TestingEmail, SendMailAcct, SendMailPW, EMailAddress, SMTPUseSSL, SMTPAuthenticate, SMTPServer, SendUsing, SMTPServerPort)
                vbYN = MsgBox("Would you like to clear temporary tables?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbSystemModal, "")
                If vbYN = vbYes Then
                    Call ClearTempTables()
                Else
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        End Using
    Catch ex As SqlException
        ErrCode = "CBC00-04"
        ErrVar = "SPCBC0001;" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message
        ErrorCounter = ErrorCounter + 1
        ErrAct = ErrorReporting.YouBrokeMyProgram("", ErrCode, ErrVar, ErrorCounter, Testing, Vers, TestingEmail, SendMailAcct, SendMailPW, EMailAddress, SMTPUseSSL, SMTPAuthenticate, SMTPServer, SendUsing, SMTPServerPort)
        If ErrAct = True Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Finally
        Conn.Close()
        Conn.Dispose()
    End Try

    'SPCBC0002 - Check if TempTable2 is empty
    Try
        Using Conn = New SqlConnection(ConnString)
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
            cmd.Connection = Conn
            cmd.CommandText = "SPCBC0002"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Conn.Open()
            data = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            data.Read()
            If data.HasRows = True Then
                ErrCode = "CBC00-06"
                ErrVar = "TempTable2"
                ErrorCounter = ErrorCounter + 1
                ErrAct = ErrorReporting.YouBrokeMyProgram("", ErrCode, ErrVar, ErrorCounter, Testing, Vers, TestingEmail, SendMailAcct, SendMailPW, EMailAddress, SMTPUseSSL, SMTPAuthenticate, SMTPServer, SendUsing, SMTPServerPort)
                vbYN = MsgBox("Would you like to clear temporary tables?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbSystemModal, "")
                If vbYN = vbYes Then
                    Call ClearTempTables()
                Else
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        End Using
    Catch ex As SqlException
        ErrCode = "CBC00-07"
        ErrVar = "SPCBC0002" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message
        ErrorCounter = ErrorCounter + 1
        ErrAct = ErrorReporting.YouBrokeMyProgram("", ErrCode, ErrVar, ErrorCounter, Testing, Vers, TestingEmail, SendMailAcct, SendMailPW, EMailAddress, SMTPUseSSL, SMTPAuthenticate, SMTPServer, SendUsing, SMTPServerPort)
        If ErrAct = True Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Finally
        Conn.Close()
        Conn.Dispose()
    End Try


    'SPCBC0003 - Fill TempTable1 from MasterOrderTable, Customer, MasterLog
    Try
        Using Conn = New SqlConnection(ConnString)
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
            cmd.Connection = Conn
            cmd.CommandText = "SPCBC0003"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrCode = "CBC00-01"
        ErrVar = "SPCBC0003" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message
        ErrorCounter = ErrorCounter + 1
        ErrAct = ErrorReporting.YouBrokeMyProgram("", ErrCode, ErrVar, ErrorCounter, Testing, Vers, TestingEmail, SendMailAcct, SendMailPW, EMailAddress, SMTPUseSSL, SMTPAuthenticate, SMTPServer, SendUsing, SMTPServerPort)
        If ErrAct = True Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Finally
        Conn.Close()
        Conn.Dispose()
    End Try


    'SPCBC0004 - Fill DataSet TempTable1 from TempTable1
    Try
        Using Conn = New SqlConnection(ConnString)
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SPCBC0004", Conn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(Me.TallySheetDataSet.TempTable1MasterOrders)
        End Using
    Catch ex As SqlException
        ErrCode = "CBC00-05"
        ErrVar = "SPCBC0004" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message
        ErrorCounter = ErrorCounter + 1
        ErrAct = ErrorReporting.YouBrokeMyProgram("", ErrCode, ErrVar, ErrorCounter, Testing, Vers, TestingEmail, SendMailAcct, SendMailPW, EMailAddress, SMTPUseSSL, SMTPAuthenticate, SMTPServer, SendUsing, SMTPServerPort)
        If ErrAct = True Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Finally
        Conn.Close()
        Conn.Dispose()
    End Try

    'handling if no rows exist
    If TallySheetDataSet.TempTable1MasterOrders.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox("No open orders")    '<-------------------------------- add error reporting?
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'SPCBC0005 - Fill TempTable2 from MasterBusinessDatesTable
    Try
        Using Conn = New SqlConnection(ConnString)
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
            cmd.Connection = Conn
            cmd.CommandText = "SPCBC0005"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    Catch ex As SqlException
        ErrCode = "CBC00-02"
        ErrVar = "SPCBC0005" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message
        ErrorCounter = ErrorCounter + 1
        ErrAct = ErrorReporting.YouBrokeMyProgram("", ErrCode, ErrVar, ErrorCounter, Testing, Vers, TestingEmail, SendMailAcct, SendMailPW, EMailAddress, SMTPUseSSL, SMTPAuthenticate, SMTPServer, SendUsing, SMTPServerPort)
        If ErrAct = True Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Finally
        Conn.Close()
        Conn.Dispose()
    End Try

    'SPCBC0006 - Fill DataSet TempTable2 from TempTable2
    Try
        Using Conn = New SqlConnection(ConnString)
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SPCBC0006", Conn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(Me.TallySheetDataSet.TempTable2BusinessDates)
        End Using
    Catch ex As SqlException
        ErrCode = "CBC00-08"
        ErrVar = "SPCBC0006" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message
        ErrorCounter = ErrorCounter + 1
        ErrAct = ErrorReporting.YouBrokeMyProgram("", ErrCode, ErrVar, ErrorCounter, Testing, Vers, TestingEmail, SendMailAcct, SendMailPW, EMailAddress, SMTPUseSSL, SMTPAuthenticate, SMTPServer, SendUsing, SMTPServerPort)
        If ErrAct = True Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Finally
        Conn.Close()
        Conn.Dispose()
    End Try

    'set ALL columns read only property to true
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(3).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(4).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(5).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(6).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(7).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(8).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(9).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(10).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(11).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(12).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(13).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(14).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(15).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(16).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(17).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(18).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(19).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(20).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(21).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(22).ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(23).ReadOnly = True

    'Refresh form
    Me.Refresh()
    DataGridView1.Refresh()

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

i have an empty handler for DataGridView1.DataError.  I added a message box and the "Ship Date" throws an error for every value in the column, then when you scroll, it throws an error for every new "Ship Date" cell that appears.  The error is for a null value being displayed in a column that doesn't accept a null value.  The null value is an attempt to suppress the value '1900-01-01' from being displayed.

Comment: Is the column shown in the 2nd image the only guilty column? What type of column is it, possibly a custom one? Are you manually handling any of the rendering or have you changed any rendering behavior? Screenshots are nice, but they do not help us reproduce the problem. A minimal example is also needed.

Comment: Yes, the "Ship Date" column is the only guilty one.  It is a bound DataGridViewComboBox Column.  The next 3 columns to the right are also bound DataGridViewComboBox columns.  Each of the 4 are bound to different sources.  I do not manually handle any rendering, nor have i changed any rendering behavior (that i am consciously aware of).  The "Pick Date" column does have its default value selected when the ship date is selected.

Comment: At one point in time, i was trying  to have the "group" ComboBox list populate based on the value selected in the "Ship Date" column, then have the "Sequence" populate based off the "Group" selection.  However, there were issues with that. The row would keep calling the cell change event, and clear all the selected values upon cell exit

Comment: Also, i removed the "AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle" and it made that column even more illegible

Comment: If you have a lot of data, [Virtual Mode in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171622(v=vs.110).aspx) might help.

Comment: yes, i have a lot of data, and i added the following code which made it MUCH worse....      `Private Sub DataGridView1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Scroll

        Me.Refresh()
        Application.DoEvents()

    End Sub`

Comment: That's an awful lot of code you showed us, and there isn't a single line of code that shows us you setting the DataGridView control to a data source or adding any rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the display errors are caused by an error message being suppressed due to a null value being displayed in a column that doesn't accept a null value. The null value is an attempt to suppress the value '1900-01-01' from being displayed.